# importing libraries on Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, spyder

File "", line 3, in 
    from secretsharing import PlaintextToHexSecretSharer

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'secretsharing'

Answer (score 1):

You need to install secretsharing

```
pip install secretsharing
```